# How can I add an html page into wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, html

Do you know how can I add existing html pages into wordpress? I'm very newbie in wordpress but I do have experience with html, css, js, php.

I have my own domain hosted in godaddy, for instance: `www.mydomain.com`.

So, I decided to install wordpress and it was successful; I can add post and pages. But I have some html & php pages, css & js files from my old site I'd like to still have access to, for instance: `www.mydomain.com/stuff/coolpage.html`, or `www.mydomain.com/apps/cooldata.php`, `mydomain.com/css/screen.css`, `mydomain.com/js/coolobject.js`.

I don't really need this pages to be linked to wordpress, but need to keep access the way they were (`mydomain.com/stuff/coolpage.html`, `mydomain.com/apps/cooldata.php`, etc).

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: If you don't want to linked with WordPress system then why don't you use those files in root directory of your site ? Then it will load normally without any hustle. But if you want to use those files from theme folder then you have to linked with WordPress and you can't linked plain html into WordPress.

Comment: nothing complicated about it...put them into same directories on new site...open as normal

Comment: @mlbd, that doesn't work... I already tried :( any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to the main directory (it contains your index.php and directories such as wp-admin, wp-content and wp-includes);
2. Create your new directory there;
3. Put the html files in your new directory;
4. Maybe you will need to change the permissions. Then use `chmod -R 755 directory`
5. And maybe you'll need to change the owner. To do that, first check the owner of the other directories with `ls -l`. If your server is Apache, for example, do `chown -R www-data:www-data directory`. But if it's not Apache replace www-data by the correct owner.

By the way, I have a WordPress site and created this page right now:
http://marceljm.com/stuff/coolpage.html

Comment: thanks @Marcel, this works!!! Another question: My main domain files are in a subfolder, ex: /home/public_html/mydomain.com,  but this main domain's wordpress installation is inside /home/public_html.  Do you know how to move this main domain's wordpress installation into the subfolder I created (/home/public_html/mydomain.com)??

Comment: Hi, Angel. Moving the main directory can be a risk. I think it can brake your site. But it's a good question for Stack Overflow :-)